Normality Issue with `gam.check()` after adding Random Effect
I am trying to run a GAM that includes 8 input variables (see code below). I first ran the model without accounting for any random effect and the gam.check() appeared to be a good fit. After I add the individual band ID as a random effect, my gam.check() plot of residual variance does not look right (tails on either end of the line). I think this is because the varying number of rows corresponding to each band ID (some adults only have a few rows, others have up to 30). How can I account for individual variation but meet the required assumptions?
#Global Model (Sample Size 5964 observations)
mod_d1 <- gam(egg_volume ~ s(year, k = 30) + (P1_WING) + (P1_CULMEN) + (first_lay_doy) +
                (ind_lay_doy) + (clutch_size) + s(n_nests) + s(parent1_age), 
             data = P1P2_eggs_clean2, method = "REML", na.action = na.fail)

summary(mod_d1)
gam.check(mod_d1)

#Add Parent Band ID- REMOVE CULMEN
mod_d1ID <- gam(egg_volume ~ s(year, k = 30) + (P1_WING) + (P1_CULMEN) +
                (ind_lay_doy) + (clutch_size) + s(n_nests) + s(parent1_age) +
                s(parent1_band, bs = "re"), data = P1P2_eggs_clean2, 
                method = "REML", na.action = na.fail)


I tried transforming the response using log (egg_volume is non-negative), I tried using weighted fits for each band # frequency, I removed outliers from all other variables.


You fitted a Gaussian GAM and the individual observations of egg_volume are unlikely to be generated from something approximated by a Gaussian because they must be positive (how would you observe an egg with zero volume?) and therefore exhibit a mean-variance relationship. You should fit something more appropriate, like a Gamma with family = Gamma(link = "log") and then start to do your model diagnostics.

What are the recommended steps to take if I re-run the model with the gamma family and the tails still exist?
